# Компилятор выдаёт ошибку: cannot convert "snippet, status" (untyped string constant) to []string при попытке загрузки видео на YouTube

Tags: golang, youtube-api

Я написал программу на Go, которая загружает видео на YouTube аккаунт из определённой директории.
Ошибка только одна:

> cannot convert "snippet, status" (untyped string constant) to []string

Интернет ничего не выдаёт по такому запросу, потому и обращаюсь за помощью к вам, коллеги.

Код:

```
...
upload := &youtube.Video{
    Snippet: &youtube.VideoSnippet{
        Title:       *title,
        Description: *description,
        CategoryId:  *category,
    },
    Status: &youtube.VideoStatus{PrivacyStatus: *privacy},
}

// API вернёт ошибку 400 Bad Request, если tags - это пустая строка.
if strings.Trim(*keywords, "") != "" {
    upload.Snippet.Tags = strings.Split(*keywords, ",")
}

call := service.Videos.Insert("snippet, status", upload)
...
```

**Поправка**: Компилятор выдаёт такую ошибку:

> cannot use "snippet, status" (type string) as type []string in
> argument to service.Videos.Insert

Ошибку из заголовка показывает VS Code.

Comment: кажется keywords приходит как nil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте посмотрим на сигнатуру метода.

VS Code ее показывает, если навести курсор на слово `Insert`

```
func (*youtube.VideosService).Insert(part []string, video *youtube.Video) *youtube.VideosInsertCall
```

Параметр `part` - массив строк.

Вы передаете туда единственное строковое значение `"snippet, status"`.

Компилятор не может преобразовать одно к другому и сообщает об этом.

Передайте на вход параметры в виде, соответствующем сигнатуре метода, скорее всего так:

```
call := service.Videos.Insert([]string{"snippet","status"}, upload)
```

Да, в примере использования api сделано ровно как у вас:

```
call := service.Videos.Insert("snippet,status", upload)
```

но видимо в библиотеке что то поменялось, а в примере это не исправили.